# In a 4-layer PCB, operating at a 8-16 MHz clock speed, should there be any copper pour on the top and bottom signal layers?

Tags: pcb-design, pcb-fabrication, pcb-layers

Currently I am designing a 4-layer PCB, with the layers as follows:

- (1st layer, top) signal
- (2nd layer) ground
- (3rd layer) power
- (4th    layer, bottom) signal

The clock frequency is either 8 MHz (running at 3.3V) or 16 MHz (running at 5V).
There are no active RF components on the board, just surface-mounted SPI-based devices. 
The total board dimensions are ~4cm x ~3cm.

My current design has no copper pour on the signal layers, but have copper pour on the ground and power layers.

So under these circumstances, would it make any difference whether or not I have a copper pour on the top and bottom signal layers?

Comment: Will this board have a data or address bus where flight-time and capacitive loading would be an issue? How complex is this board? Mixed signal types?

Comment: There is no address bus; the individual SPI devices are activated via digital outputs from a microcontroller. There are data transmitted from the SPI devices, so perhaps that can be considered a data bus. The board is purely digital, no mixed signal types.

Comment: Remember the copper is already there. You pay the board house to etch away what is not needed. Extra ground pour is ok but 2 layers of it means a lot of vias.

Comment: What edge speeds and lengths of trace do you expect? Must you pass FCC susceptability and emissions tests?

Comment: @analogsystemsrf I looked into it, assuming a 1/6 of the rise/fall time (rise/fall time assumed to be 10% of the period) as a design guideline and also assuming the electron speed of 152,400,000 m/s (based on a post from here, https://www.quora.com/At-what-clock-frequency-do-PCB-layout-engineers-need-to-start-considering-high-speed-digital-design-issues), the allowable trace length works out to be ~31 cm for 8MHz and ~15.5cm for 16 MHz; in my design, the longest trace is only about 3 cm.; so I think there should be no design problem in that regard.

Comment: @analogsystemsrf And no, I do not need to pass FCC tests, the design is more for research purposes. How would edge speeds and trace lengths influence whether or not copper pours are required?

Comment: the board house recycles their etchant and reclaims that copper to use for plating up thin layers (to make them thicker - they charge for this), or to sell on the scrap market (another profit). etching is a gain to them.

Comment: If you have very fast edges, the copper pours will tend to become antennas because the traces will couple to the same-layer pours. Read what Neal_UK says below.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

All copper on the board should be consciously designed.

I am against copper pours on principle, because they seem to cause more problems than they solve - increased stray capacitance, confusion about where return currents are flowing, unintentional coupling between signals, or creation of an antenna. It can complicate debug and modification as well.

They seem to lead to a lazy mindset, where the designer thinks 'well there's lots of copper on the board, surely the grounding will be OK now!' A copper pour is [unnecessary, and insufficient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Necessity_and_sufficiency) to achieve a good board.

There are good reasons to use a copper pour, thermal conductivity, reducing the amount of etch solution used, improving thickness tolerance, reduction of warping, beefing up of tracks, but 'should' isn't one of them.

Comment: All agreed. Just to add one consideration: with extra copper parasitic capacitance may couple between remote and unrelated circuits, like switching power supply and op amp feedback on other side of the board.

Comment: Thanks, in that case, I will keep the top and bottom signal layers of the design without any copper pour.

Answer (score 3):

~4Mhz can be done single-sided - Sega did a Z-80 based home computer on single-sided FR2. 16Mhz is not radically more especially when the traces are only 5cm or so long (vs 20cm in the single sieded computer)

With only 5cm traces, you can probably do the same for your design, (although double sided makes routing easier, and more layers will give you a ground plane if you really need it.

If you put both the power pours close together they act as another power supply de-coupling capacitor.

Surface pours can be useful for heat-sinking if you have some power parts could benefit from that, but act as antennas for electrical fields so don't use them for fast or high-impedance signal nodes.

Unless you're making this in production quantities the board house only charges for the area of the PCB material and the number of layers, so you don't get any credit for the copper they reclaim.
Copper is expensive so the don't flush used etchant doiwn the drain but instead recycle it, reducing both waste and costs. So they're probably glad to have large etched areas.

Comment: Interesting - didn't know about sega doing single-sided boards, but it looks like they did 3 different designs: the SG-1000, the SG-1000 II and the Sega Mark III are all on single-sided boards, and seems didn't need all that many links to be applied, either.  Incidentally, they didn't run at 4MHz - the CPU ran at about 3.6MHz, but the graphics processor ran at 10.7MHz and its dedicated RAM was connected via a bus that could switch twice (i.e. to provide RAS and CAS commands) in 3 processor cycles, so was effectively ~7MHz.  But then, 7MHz can be done on *breadboard* (google: grant searle CPM).